# Reporting Copied (Stolen) Product Descriptions to Google

Tags: google, copyright

If a competitor copies your unique product descriptions on an eCommerce site, what is the proper way to report the copied content to google? Do you have to take different action for Web Organic search and Shopping search?

Comment: From my experience -- Google does not care to do anything about this -- our content (product description, images, URL hierarchy and even parts of interface) was copied letter-by-letter so many times on different sites (sites from the same country as well as abroad), sometimes without changing anything, even leaving "contact OUR_PHONE_NUMBER" etc in place. We stopped worrying about this long time ago. Maybe because we as e-commerce site were doing product description as a compilation of most important parts from the manufacturer site .. so it is already kind of duplicate ... unsure...

Comment: @LazyOne - I wouldn't worry about descriptions with the manufacturer description as the core idea either, since everyone can get those and reword them etc. Detailed analysis of the product is the type of info we want to protect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can submit a DMCA take down request using [this form](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/dmca-notice?pli=1). It should cover both Regular search and Shopping search.

Comment: Thanks, the form you posted looks more relevant than the one I found.